# How to add field to ValuesQuerySet

Tags: python, django

I have the following code.

```
    pages = PagePromotion.objects.values('page_url').distinct().annotate(
        freq=Count('id'))
```

Which my pages output is..

```
ipdb> pages[0]
{'freq': 7, 'page_url': u'/'}
```

and

```
ipdb> FlatPage.objects.get(url=pages[0]['page_url']).id
1
```

But when I do,

```
pages[0]['id'] = FlatPage.objects.get(url=pages[0]['page_url']).id
```

It still gives me the old result

> {'freq': 7, 'page_url': u'/'}

when i ask for pages[0] . Is there any other way to extend a ValuesQueryset object

Comment: I'm not sure what this is supposed to be showing. Why should the values change?

Comment: why not just do `pages = PagePromotion.objects.values('id', 'page_url').distinct().annotate(
        freq=Count('id'))`

Comment: Its not the same, id i want does not belong to PagePromotion, I want to have the ValuesQuerySet as dict and extend it with additional parameters not from the model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After converting the ValuesQuerySet to list my problem solved;

```
pages = list(pages)

ipdb> pages[0]['hede'] = 2
ipdb> pages[0]
{'hede': 2, 'freq': 7, 'page_url': u'/'}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also do something like this:

```
for page in pages:
    page.update({'hede': 2})
```

The main part here is **update** which sets new property 'hede' with it's value to object in your pages ValuesQuerySet.